# How do you run "Rails Runner" in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

here is what I am trying to do: Find if anyone has tweeted about a specific course offered. If someone has indeed tweeted about it, I'd like to save that tweet to my Tweet Model and then display that tweet in the corresponding course page.

The scripts works locally by running `rails runner get_tweets.rb` but on Heroku it seems that the script gets executed but doesn't write to the database. In heroku I am running `heroku run rails runner get_tweets.rb` (using the Cedar stack).

```
def get_course_tweets
  @courses = Course.all
  @courses.each do |course|
    url = course.url
    tweets = Twitter.search(url, {:rpp => 100, :recent => true, :show_user => true})
    tweets.each do |tweet_info|
      unless Tweet.find_by_tweet_id(tweet_info.id).present?
        tweet = Tweet.new
        tweet.course_id = course.id
        tweet.tweet_id = tweet_info.id
        tweet.tweet_text = tweet_info.text
        tweet.from_user = tweet_info.from_user
        begin
          tweet.save!
        rescue => error
          puts error
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Edit:

The current error I get from rescue is the following:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  value "186306985577299969" is out of range for type integer : INSERT INTO "tweets" ("book_id", "course_id", "created_at", "from_user", "tutorial_id",     "tweet_already_exists", "tweet_id", "tweet_posted_to_reviews", "tweet_text", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id"
```

Comment: Perhaps you should actually print out the error if it does `rescue` and see if any are occuring?

Comment: Hi Andrew, here is the error I get: PG::Error: ERROR:  value "186306985577299969" is out of range for type integer
: INSERT INTO "tweets" ("book_id", "course_id", "created_at", "from_user", "tutorial_id", "tweet_already_exists", "tweet_id", "tweet_posted_to_reviews", "tweet_text", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen from your error

> value "186306985577299969" is out of range for type integer

you need to use a different datatype (for `tweet_id`, I believe), presumably a [`BIGINT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT), which ranges from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807.

To do so in Rails you can pass `:limit => 8` in your `up` migration:

```
change_column :tweets, :tweet_id, :integer, :limit => 8
```

Note that you should *always* do some sort of logging or reporting when you `rescue`, or else bugs like this become very difficult to track down because they silently get bypassed.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you so much! Here is what I ended up doing:

    `t.column :tweet_id, :bigint`

Out of curiosity, what would the :limit => 8 do in this case?

Comment: It instructs it to use an 8-byte integer, which is a `BIGINT`, I didn't expect `:bigint` to work as a type in the migration as it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere I could find.

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API actually sends back two types of ID's for tweets and users etc., one is a number, where as the other is a string representation of the number. This is because it's a very real possibility that they will have so many tweets and users that the ID's can overflow in different implementations. If you use the String as your value when inserting it shouldn't happen anymore.

The field is called id_str